# split character columns and get names of field in string

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

I need to split a column that contains information into several columns.
I'd use `tstrsplit` but the same kind of information is not in the same order among the rows and I need to extract the name of the new column within the variable. Important to know: there can be many pieces of information (fields to become new variables) and I don't know all of them, so I don't want a "field by field" solution.

Below is an example of what I have:

```
library(data.table)

myDT <- structure(list(chr = c("chr1", "chr2", "chr4"), pos = c(123L,
                  435L, 120L), info = c("type=3;end=4", "end=6", "end=5;pos=TRUE;type=2"
                  )), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-3L))

#    chr pos                  info
#1: chr1 123          type=3;end=4
#2: chr2 435                 end=6
#3: chr4 120 end=5;pos=TRUE;type=2
```

And I'd like to get:

```
#    chr pos end  pos type
#1: chr1 123   4 <NA>    3
#2: chr2 435   6 <NA> <NA>
#3: chr4 120   5 TRUE    2
```

A most straightforward way to get that would be much appreciated! (*Note: I'm not willing to go with a dplyr/tidyr way*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `regex` and the `stringi` packages:

```
setDT(myDT) # After creating data.table from structure()

library(stringi)

fields <- unique(unlist(stri_extract_all(regex = "[a-z]+(?==)", myDT$info)))
patterns <- sprintf("(?<=%s=)[^;]+", fields)
myDT[, (fields) := lapply(patterns, function(x) stri_extract(regex = x, info))]
myDT[, !"info"]

    chr  pos type end
1: chr1 <NA>    3   4
2: chr2 <NA> <NA>   6
3: chr4 TRUE    2   5
```

Edit: To get the correct type it *seems* (?) `type.convert()` can be used:

```
myDT[, (fields) := lapply(patterns, function(x) type.convert(stri_extract(regex = x, info), as.is = TRUE))]
```

Comment: I get a very long warning "Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table ..."

Comment: also type and end are character here, not sure if that's expected

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thanks for commenting. (1) (This warning is (I think) caused by the data.table being created by `structure()` I've updated the answer to avoid this issue (2) They are characters on purpose... I felt parsing them correctly would be a hard and a separate question. It seems you solved it though in your answer and I will take a look and see if I can learn something new.

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing your data is coming from a [VCF file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Call_Format), if so there is a dedicated tool for such problems - [bcftools](http://www.htslib.org/doc/bcftools.html).

Let's create example *VCF* file for testing:

```
# subset some data from 1000genomes data
tabix -h ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nih.gov/1000genomes/ftp/release/20100804/ALL.2of4intersection.20100804.genotypes.vcf.gz 17:1471000-1472000 > myFile.vcf
# zip it and index:
bgzip -c myFile.vcf > myFile.vcf.gz
tabix -p vcf myFile.vcf.gz
```

Now we can use *bcftools*. Here as an example we are subsetting *AF* and *DP* from *INFO* column:

```
bcftools query -f '%CHROM %POS %INFO/AF %INFO/DP \n' myFile.vcf.gz 
17  1471199  1916 0.088
17  1471538  2445 0.016
17  1471611  2733 0.239
17  1471623  2815 0.003
17  1471946  1608 0.007
17  1471959  1612 0.014
17  1471975  1610 0.179
```

See the manual for more [query](http://www.htslib.org/doc/bcftools.html#query) options.

Comment: If you have a multi-sample vcf and want to have the samples on the left hand column and then each column being a different variant with the GT (i.e. transpose your suggestion above) can it be done in bcftools alone?

Comment: @tacrolimus ask as new question, linking to this post, with [bioinformatics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bioinformatics) tag.

Answer (score 3):

For now, I managed to get what I want with the following code:

```
newDT <- reshape(splitstackshape::cSplit(myDT, "info", sep=";", "long")[, 
                  c(.SD, tstrsplit(info, "="))], 
                 idvar=c("chr", "pos"), direction="wide", timevar="V4", drop="info")
setnames(newDT, sub("V5\\.", "", names(newDT)))

newDT
#    chr pos type end  pos
#1: chr1 123    3   4 <NA>
#2: chr2 435 <NA>   6 <NA>
#3: chr4 120    2   5 TRUE
```

**Two options to improve the lines above, thanks to @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 (who gave them in comments) :**

. with a double `cSplit` prior to `dcast`:

```
cSplit(cSplit(myDT, "info", ";", "long"), "info", "=")[, dcast(.SD, chr + pos ~ info_1, value.var = "info_2")]
```

. with `cSplit`/`trstrplit` and `dcast` instead of `reshape`:

```
cSplit(myDT, "info", ";", "long")[, c("t1", "t2") := tstrsplit(info, "=", fixed = TRUE)][, dcast(.SD, chr + pos ~ t1, value.var = "t2")]
```

Comment: I'd do a double `cSplit`, like this: `cSplit(cSplit(myDT, "info", ";", "long"), "info", "=")[, dcast(.SD, chr + pos ~ info_1, value.var = "info_2")]`.

Comment: Or, the same concept: `cSplit` followed by `tstrsplit`, followed by `dcast`: `cSplit(myDT, "info", ";", "long")[, c("t1", "t2") := tstrsplit(info, "=", fixed = TRUE)][, dcast(.SD, chr + pos ~ t1, value.var = "t2")]`.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 Thanks very much! Both are great, with a special for the double `cSplit` option :-)

Answer (score 3):

We could split on `";"` then reshape wide-to-long, then split again on `"="`, then reshape back to long-to-wide:

```
dcast(
  melt(dt[,  paste0("col", 1:3) := tstrsplit(info, split = ";") ],
       id.vars = c("chr", "pos", "info"))[, -c("info", "variable")][
         ,c("x1", "x2") := tstrsplit(value, split = "=")][
           ,value := NULL][ !is.na(x1), ],
  chr + pos ~ x1, value.var = "x2")

#     chr pos end  pos type
# 1: chr1 123   4 <NA>    3
# 2: chr2 435   6 <NA> <NA>
# 3: chr4 120   5 TRUE    2
```

---

An improved / more readible version:

```
dt[, paste0("col", 1:3) := tstrsplit(info, split = ";")
   ][, melt(.SD, id.vars = c("chr", "pos", "info"), na.rm = TRUE)
     ][, -c("info", "variable")
       ][, c("x1", "x2") := tstrsplit(value, split = "=")
         ][, dcast(.SD, chr + pos ~ x1, value.var = "x2")]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it :

```r
library(data.table)

myDT <- structure(list(chr = c("chr1", "chr2", "chr4"), pos = c(123L,
                                                                435L, 120L), info = c("type=3;end=4", "end=6", "end=5;pos=TRUE;type=2"
                                                                )), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-3L))

R_strings <- paste0("list(", chartr(";", ",", myDT$info),")")
lists <- lapply(parse(text=R_strings),eval)
myDT[,info:=NULL]
myDT <- cbind(myDT,rbindlist(lists, fill = TRUE))
myDT
#>     chr pos type end  pos
#> 1: chr1 123    3   4   NA
#> 2: chr2 435   NA   6   NA
#> 3: chr4 120    2   5 TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I don't get the need to change ";" into "," and not fond of `eval(parse(text=...))`... but thanks nonetheless for your answer

Comment: I can't argue with personal taste but `parse` has a bad rep because it's often used for wrong reason, here is precisely its appropriate use case, going from string to code. You have formatted text, but not formatted for R, and you have named lists, so my first line makes it code for a R list, by changing "a;b" into "list(a,b)". Then we evaluate it and make a table out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use separate calls to `sub` for each desired extracted field, e.g. for `type`:

```
myDT$type <- sub("^.*\\btype=([^;]+)\\b.*$", "\\1", myDT$info)
```

Comment: I don't know all the fileds that will occur and they can be a lot so this is not an option

Comment: Fair enough; I didn't know this when I posted this answer.

Comment: I'll add it (btw you don't give desired output, your answer misses some lines...)