# Remove all text after : in multiple columns in a table in R

Tags: r, gsub

Data:

```
CHROM 1                         2                 3 

ABC   0/1:PASS:123:4214 0/1:PASS:546:4656 0/0:PASS:444:865 
DEF   0/1:PASS:123:4214 0/1:PASS:546:4656 0/0:PASS:444:865
GFD   0/1:PASS:123:4214 0/1:PASS:546:4656 0/0:PASS:444:865
```

Desired output:

```
CHROM 1   2   3 

ABC   0/1 0/1 0/0 
DEF   0/1 0/1 0/0
GFD   0/1 0/1 0/0
```

I have tried:

```
sub(':*', ''. data) 
gsub(':*', ''. data)
```

But this give me a list as an output rather than a table and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong

Your help would be much appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) sub(":.*", "", as.character(x)))`

Comment: thanks that worked after I converted the output into a data frame (was a list initially)

Comment: If it is a VCF file, then use bcftools to extract GT field.

Comment: I have! I have tranposed it with datamash in linux to get the sample IDs as a column. Does bcftools allow you to get a clean output with samples on the left and then GT in subsequent columns with each column being a variant? @zx8754

Comment: Yes, use the right tool for the job, see example my answer for extracting certain columns from VCF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59104151/680068 In your case you would need `%GT`